# Unable to add files in GIT repository by "git add . " command

Tags: git, automation

I am in a directory and trying unsuccessfully to add `.gitignore` to my git repo.

I've tried the following commands:

```
git add --all

git status

git add --force

git stash
```

I've tried creating a new dir again from scratch. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, and especially don't post **links** to pictures of text. Just include the relevant information in your question, properly formatted as a code sample. The information provided in your question is insufficient for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your image link, the files are green in color which means the command `git add .` is working.
Just after that, commit your files using `git commit -m "<your commit message>"`
Then check your git status using `git status`.
Your directory must be clean!